# Move window to iframe without reloading

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

I wan't to make a userscript that will persist with its instance even if I click on a link.

To make a script instance (ie. variables etc) persist, I need to have the page I'm broswing in iframe, which is a child of the window where script is running. And also, parents document location must be same as the inner document location - otherwise I'd have problems with same origin policy.

That said, I wan't to turn this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
     ...page contents...
  </body>
</html>
```

into this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...here is my userscript running...

  </head>
  <body>
     <iframe style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
        ...move the whole original window here...

     </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Unles a link has `target="_blank/_parent/_top"` all browsing activity should happen in the inner iframe, while the parent window shall not be refreshed (which would cause the script lose all variables).

One way to do that would be simply creating an iframe with same url like the url of my site:

```
var container = document.createElement("iframe");
container.src = window.location;
```

However, such approach would cause page reload as well as lose of all data (filled forms, scrolling).

So to move the `window` with all its contents to an iframe. Is that possible?

Comment: Tomas, this is a really interesting question that I am currently struggling with myself.  Have you found an answer?  So far, as I see it, the iframe's window and document references need to be changed, plus whatever references it has to the html, body, and head tags.  Sadly, if these references are enclosed in a function on the window object, there is pretty much no way to change them.  Have you had any luck?

Comment: Nope, still waiting for an answer.

Comment: Yeah, all my research so far has indicated that it's not possible, which is a massive shame.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could get the contents of document.head.outerHTML and document.body.outerHTML, combine them into a string, base64 encode it, then use the result to construct a dataURL, which you then set as the iframe's src.

Though I could see recursion turning the idea into an effect similar to pointing a video camera at a screen showing it's outut.

Interesting question. Bookmarked.

Comment: I'll make sure that the inner page in the iframe will be avare of the fact, that it's already maintained by the userscript. Good point though.